# Oracle SQL: How to write below SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, count

There is a table t1:

```
id type 
1    a
1    b
2    c
2    a
3    a
3    a
4    a
```

Now I need to check if the id only has type `a` and the count is 1 (single), i.e., only id 4 satisfies this condition in the data above

```
SELECT type, COUNT (1)
FROM t1
where id = :id
GROUP BY type
HAVING COUNT (1) = 1;
```

I use the above SQL query to get the data and then use it in code. It's not a good solution, can anyone help me to get the correct result with one SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
SELECT id
FROM t1
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MIN(type) = 'a';
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this is the better solution

Answer (score 3):

I'd group by the ID and filter on two counts:

1. Total count is 1
2. Count of rows that aren't type a (using a case statement) is 0

```
SELECT   id
FROM     t1
GROUP BY id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN type <> 'a' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a simple aggredated query with a `HAVING BY` clause that ensures that only one row exists and that its type is equal to `'a'`.

```
SELECT id
FROM t1
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 and SUM(DECODE(type, 'a', 0, 1)) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `id` in `group by` clause & just filter out the `type`s with `having` clause :

```
SELECT id
FROM t1
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(type) = MAX(type) AND MIN(type) = 'a';
```